# Changing fermentation

Tags: fermentation, beginner

I just made my first brew and I started the fermentation process in a plastic container. Should I transfer the brew into a glass fermenter? It's only been sitting in the plastic one for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it, it's fine. Plenty of people ferment in plastic, either buckets or better bottles.